# Merging multiple tables in Azure mobile service

Tags: sql-server, json, azure, azure-mobile-services

When writing web services in C# we create objects and then serialize and send it to client. I wanna do something similar to that in Azure mobile service

I have 2 Tables

1. OrderHead
2. OrderRow

Orderhead has the order information (totalprice, customerid, date created etc) and one record in OrderHead table can have multiple items in OrderRow. Orderrow table has details about items ordered (ordered itemid, itemname, price etc)

How can I join them together and get a single response from a custom api. Something similar to below

```
{
    "orderheadid": "3424232",
    "totalprice": 423423,
    "orderrow": [
        {
            "itemid": "32423",
            "itemprice": 2
        },
        {
            "itemid": "23",
            "itemprice": 333
        },
        {
            "itemid": "223",
            "itemprice": 4
        }
    ]
}
```

Or should I be calling each services separately from client site?

I know I can do INNER JOIN query using mssql object, but then it won't return a structured JSON object as given above. Can someone enlighten me please.

Thanks for your time in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Retrieve the value from table 1 and assign it to a variable
2. Retrieve the value from table 2 and add it as a new attribute to the variable created above.

Something like below will do

```
var orderHead;
var orderRow;
var orderRowTable  = table.getTable('orderhead');
orderHeadTable.where({
//any other query details
    customerid:request.user.userId
    }).read({
        success:function(result){
            console.log(result.length);
            if(result.length===0){
                response.send(400, { message : 'Cart empty' });
            }else{
                orderHead = result[0];
                getOrderRows()
            }
        },
        error:function(){
            response.send(400, { message : 'error while reading order information' });
        }
    });

function getOrderRows(){
     var orderRowTable  = table.getTable('orderrow');
    orderRowTable.where({
        orderheadid:orderHead.id
    }).read({
       success:function(result){
           if(result && result.length===0){
               response.send(400, { message : 'Cart empty' });
           }else{
                orderRows = result;
                orderHead.orderRows = orderRows;
                response.send(200, orderHead);        
           }
       },
       error:function(){
           response.send(400, { message : 'error while reading order information - row' });
       } 
    });
}
```